# Kotlin: Generic type functions: Out-projected type ... prohibits the use of

Tags: kotlin, generics

Given a class:

```
class Data<T>{
    fun get(): T = Something as T
    fun update(item: T) { }
}
```

How to do something like this?

```
fun alterData(d: Data<*>){
    d.update(d.get())
}
```

The function "alterData" won't compile:

Out-projected type 'Data<*>' prohibits the use of 'fun update(item: T)'

**Update**:
The caller of alterData() don't know the type, so this is not possible:

```
fun <T>alterData(d: Data<T>){
    d.update(d.get())
}
```

The only way I found to bypass this limitation is by means of writing the method inside the class, but that's breaks abstraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` basically means that you don't know what the type `T` is in this case, so it could be anything.

Because you have defined `d` as `Data<*>` the call `d.get()` returns `Any?`. The compiler cannot know what type of data `d` contains. Therefor you have to expect anything that's valid for `T`, including `null`.

Because you have defined `d` as `Data<*>` the call `d.update(…)` accepts only `Nothing`, i.e. no value at all. The compiler cannot know what type of data `d` is allowed to receive. Therefor it cannot accept anything as it may or may not be valid here.

What you want to tell the compiler is that there is a relationship between what comes out of `d` (out projection) and what goes into `d` (in projection):

```kotlin
fun <T> alterData(d: Data<T>) {
    d.update(d.get())
}
```

Now the compiler knows that whatever comes out of `d` (through `.get()`) is of the same type as what you put into `d` (through `.update(…)`). In both cases that type is referred to as `T`.

Note that the "type parameter" `T` doesn't have to have same name as your `Data<T>` declaration. The following is equally valid to indicate the relationship:

```kotlin
fun <Something> alterData(d: Data<Something>) {
    d.update(d.get())
}
```

It may be easier to understand if you break the code down further:

```kotlin
fun alterData(d: Data<*>) {
    // `value` is of type `Any?` because we don't know `T` of `Data`
    val value = d.get()

    // `update` rejects `Any?` b/c we don't know `T` and it may not be valid
    d.update(value)
}
```

```kotlin
fun <Something> alterData(d: Data<Something>) {
    // `value` is of type `Something` b/c we know that `T` of `Data` is `Something`
    val value = d.get()

    // `update` accepts `Something` b/c we know `T` is `Something`
    d.update(value)
}
```

As in your case neither the caller nor the callee (`alterData`) know the actual type of `T` you"ll have to tell the compiler to ignore compile-time type safety by using a cast.

You can do that either in the caller or the callee. Where it makes more sense depends on the actual use case. Usually the caller knows a little more about the context and the possible type of `T` than the callee, so it makes sense to perform a cast there.

```kotlin
fun foo(d: Data<*>) {
   // ignore all type safety for `T`
   alterData(d as Data<Any?>)
}
```

The callee `alterData` immediately passes a value that it receives from one `Data` instance (`d`) back to the same instance. In that case it's safe to assume that that can never go wrong, given your definition of `class Data`. If that's the case then you can safely perform the case in the `alterData` function:

```kotlin
fun alterData(d: Data<*>){
    // ignore type safety and allow any value to be passed into `d`
    (d as Data<Any?>).update(d.get())
}
```

Both approaches will raise a compiler warning that you could ignore using `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`.

Comment: That's ok, very well explained, but the caller don't know the type, it just needs to receive some values from the class and call another method of the same class supplying the values, I update the question for clarity

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I've extended my answer accordingly.